# Is it possible to simulate locations without connection to Xcode?

Tags: ios, location, core-location, gpx

I created GPX file. I started simulate locations through GPX file. It is fully workable solution. But I have a problem.

**1)** Run an app and start simulate locations through Xcode. It is ok.

**2)** Switch off a cable from device.

**3)** Restart app on device

**4)** I didn’t get any simulated locations.

Is it possible to simulate locations without connection to Xcode?

Comment: Yes, you can see the https://www.libimobiledevice.org/. itools is developed by the cross-platform software protocol library.

Comment: Look for "idevicesetlocation" https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice/blob/25059d4c7d75e03aab516af2929d7c6e6d4c17de/tools/idevicesetlocation.c